# Promise confusion

Tags: javascript, promise

I have some issues with promise usage (coming from callback horror)

I created a Fiddle but its not working... this is how I understood that it worked

1) create for each async promise
   2) use then after each of the async

```
var a = new Tester("male");

var test = a.getFirst("test1").then("test2").then("test3");
console.log(test);
```

it does nothing...

https://jsfiddle.net/awzh91yv/

Comment: It's because you're not waiting for test to get initialized. Add another `.then` after your test3 and then `console.log` it.

Comment: What is it supposed to output? `a.lastname`? And that's not something you'd use a promise for.

Comment: @PeterMader its only a dirty example... I have allot of callbacks that all do async stuff (that is based on some returns from previous running functions)

Comment: WTH were you expecting `then` to do with a string argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing your promise values along the chain. `.then()` needs to be passed the value - so it'd look something like `.then(val => a.getSecond("Jim")) ...` etc

I've updated your fiddle to work somewhat.

https://jsfiddle.net/awzh91yv/1/

Comment: I like it and i understand it...although I totally dont like the arrow functions...totally not readable to be honest...:)

Comment: You'll get used to it - and then you'll love them.

Comment: I had a question why do you do 'val =>' for the methods where you don't expect a return variable for the next variable...if i try without them it goes directly to the following .then

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you chain a promise. You'd call a function in the `then`, it doesn't magically call your class' methods in order you created them. Try

```
a.getFirst("foo")
    .then(() => a.getSecond("bar"))
    .then(() => a.getLast("baz"))
    .then(console.log);
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awzh91yv/2/)

Above being said, that's not something you'd use a promise for.

Comment: what do you mean by you should not use a promise for this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = new Tester("male");

var test = a.getFirst(function(){
                    return "test1";
                })
                .then(function(){
                    return "test2";
                })
                .then(function(){
                    return "test3";
                })
                .then(function(test){
                    console.log(test);
                });
```

This would give the desired result since it waits for the promise to finish

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dso1j6js/)

Comment: Calling `then` with a string instead of a function is essentially a no-op, see the comment on the MDN page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then